# SIP Linphone multiple instance

Tags: sip, linphone

I am trying to start multiple Linphone applications on my system, I am not able to do this. Somewhere I read that we can start two instances of the Linphone application. One as Linphone and the other as sudo Linphone.

If anyone has any idea about this, please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help (http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/linphone-users/2010-09/msg00001.html):

> Note, we launch each Linphone with different config files in order to
>   use separate ports & separate audio cards..

Comment: Hi Thanks for the pointer. Just to tell you I just got to know about Linphone, so not sure what config you are talking about.. Could you please elaborate, where is the config file and what all to configure

Comment: Linphone has a linphonerc configuration file in which all SIP, RTP, sound, video settings are read and stored. By default no configuration file is required and linphone always generates a default one at first startup. Take a look: http://www.linphone.org/eng/documentation/dev/tuning-linphone.html

Comment: thank you for the pointer.. could you please answer one more question...This is just for the testing purpose. I want to create two sip accounts using my linphone. The sever is my computer only. Can I call one account from the other account?

Assume my accounts are dharam@192.168.2.6:5080 and newaccount@192.168.2.6:5080

Can I make call to the other sip account using one sip account?

The whole set up is on my local system

Comment: Hi, thre actually dont say how to start multiple instance. When I type linphone in terminal while one is already runing, it gives message that it centers back the runing instance and exits.